# recursion issue (2d quadrature)

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

So I have a program that implements an adaptive 2D trapezoidal rule on the function x^2 + y^2 < 1, but it seems that the recursion isn't working -- the program here is a modified form of a (working) 1D trapezoidal method so I'm not sure where the code breaks down, it should return PI:

```
double trapezoidal(d_fp_d f,
                   double a, double b,
                   double c, double d) { //helper function
    return 0.25*(b-a)*(d-c)*
    (f(a, c)+f(a, d) +
     f(b, c)+f(b, d));
}

double atrap( double a, double b, double c, double d, d_fp_d f, double tol )
 {// helper function

 return atrap1(a, b, c, d, f, tol );
 }
double atrap1( double a, double b, double c, double d, d_fp_d f, double tol)
{
 //implements 2D trap rule 
    static int level = 0;
    const static int minLevel = 4;
    const static int maxLevel = 30;
    ++level;
    double m1 = (a + b)/2.0;
    double m2 = (c + d)/2.0;
    double coarse = trapezoidal(f,a,b,c,d);
    double fine = 
      trapezoidal(f, a, m1, c, m2)
    + trapezoidal(f, a, m1, m2, d)
    + trapezoidal(f, m1, b, c, m2)
    + trapezoidal(f, m1, b, m2, d);
    ++fnEvals;
    if( level< minLevel
       || ( abs( fine - coarse ) > 3.0*tol && level < maxLevel ) ){

            fine =  atrap1( a, m1, c, m2, f,tol/4.0)
            + atrap1( a, m1, m2, d, f, tol/4.0)
            + atrap1(m1, b, c, m2, f, tol/4.0)
            + atrap1(m1, b, m2, d, f,tol/4.0);

        }

    --level;
    return fine;
}
```

where the function is given by

```
double ucircle( double x, double y)
{
    return x*x + y*y < 1 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
}
```

and my main function is

```
int main()
{
   double a, b, c, d;
    cout << "Enter a: " <<endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter b: " <<endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter c: " <<endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Enter d: " <<endl;
    cin >> d;

    cout << "The approximate integral is: " << atrap( a, b, c, d, ucircle, 1.0e-5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the program won't work, I was wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you do any debugging? What did you learn?

Comment: It's supposed to run for up to maxLevel = 30 levels of recursion (and no fewer than minlevel = 6 levels)

Comment: @Emir And what is your input?

Comment: @BigBoss it's (a, b, c, d) = (-1, 1, -1, 1)

Comment: Is it too much trouble to give us a minimal complete example?

Answer (score 1):

It will not actually run forever, but it actually run for a very long time that you think it is running for ever and that is the reason: in first run `level` is one and function enter your `if` and it call itself 4 times, now consider first time: it is also enter the `if` and call itself 4 more times and it continue ... for correctly chosen input like one specified by you, condition `abs(fine - coarse)` is always `true` so only thing that can stop the flow from entering the `if` is `level` that will be increased and then decreased so your function will be called almost `4^30` and that's really a big number that you can't see its end in an hour or 2!

Comment: but level is a static int -- it should increase when atrap1 calls itself in the recursion, right?

Comment: Of course, but you decrease it each time that you return from function. So its depth can't be more than 30 but it doesn't mean it can grow to that number(4^30) with an structure like tree! just test it for a level of 3 and you see what is happening with 30

Comment: ah, you're right -- how else do you recommend I track the recursion?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your algorithm and its purpose, I just know C++. But as far as I understand from your code you need a lot of actions, so try finding another algorithm for this

Answer (score 0):

Like BigBoss already wrote, your program should finish, it would just take a long time since 30 recursions mean `4^30` function calls for `atrap1`, which is `1152921504606846976`. Just let that number sink in.

Here are some more things to consider:

- You probably wanted to use `fabs` instead of `abs` in the "break condition". (I think you should get a warning for integer conversion - or something similar - for this) `abs` may return unpredictable values for `float` or `double` parameters. *Very high values*.
- `tol` seems to be a variable that represents a target precision value. However, with each recursion you further increase this target precision. At the 10th recursion it's already about `1E-11`. Not sure this is intended. Whatever `tol` means.

  You probably don't want the `/4.0` (the `.0` is redundant by the way) in your recursive calls.
- You do compile this with optimization, right?
- `trapezoidal`, `minLevel`, `maxLevel` could be macros.
- Your function does not like threaded execution due to `level` being static. You should make it a parameter for `atrap1`.